# Visual Studio 2012 C++ multi-threading using "parallel_for_each"

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2012

I made a simulation code that has many iterations. I want to reduce the calculation time. So I decided to to try multi-threading and now Im having a big trouble with it..

Since the code is too long I made an example code below

```
double * INPUT1=function1();
int INPUT2=10;

for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
  function2(INPUT1[i], INPUT2);
}
```

Now I want to change the standard for loop into "parallel_for_each" loop, which i believe is the fastest(uses GPU). Basically, the problem I have is, how to insert the inputs from the main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that `parallel_for_each` is really using the GPU. I think it is using multiple cores on a normal CPU. Your case could be rewritten similar to the following code snippet:

```
// Example
#include <iostream>
#include <ppl.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace concurrency;

void function2(double i, int input2)
{
    std::cout << i*input2 << " ";
}

std::vector<double> function1()
{
    return{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> input = function1();
    int input2 = 10;

    parallel_for_each(input.begin(), input.end(), [&input2](double i) {function2(i, input2); });

    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

`parallel_for_each` lives in the `concurrency namespace` of `ppl.h`. To get more information about how to use this construct, you can consult the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728080.aspx). In general, once you start using parallel constructions, make sure that you do only parallelize functions which can work completely independently for each iteration. If you are serious about parallelization, you should also have a look at [openmp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbyca0bh.aspx).